# Safari does not allow absolute position a element when using column-count

Tags: html, css, safari

I want to style divs in a container and give it an position:absolute.

The parent container uses column-count=3 to layout the elements.

This works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but Safari does not position the element right.

This is how it looks like in Chrome and Firefox:
[image: This is what I want]

This is Safari:

[image: Safari]

```css
    html,
    body {
        margin: 0px;
        min-height: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .app {
        display: flex;
    }

    .list-wrapper {
        margin-top: 25px;
    }

    ul li:first-child {
        margin-top: 0px;
    }

    ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style-type: none;
        column-gap: 0px;
        column-count: 3;
        column-width: 200px;
    }

    li {
        border: 1px solid black;
        margin: 4px;
        padding: 20px;
        overflow: hidden;
        break-inside: avoid-column;
    }

    h1 {
        height: 30px;
        min-height: 30px;
        line-height: 30px;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    li h1::before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        width: 24px;
        height: 24px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-42px);
        background: #7fb8ff;
        border: 3px solid #0072ff;
        box-shadow: 0 0 4px #aaa;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="app">
        <div class="list-wrapper">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div>
                        <h1>Title 1</h1>
                        <p>Just some content</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div>
                        <h1>Title 2</h1>
                        <p>Just some content</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div>
                        <h1>Title 3</h1>
                        <p>Just some content</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div>
                        <h1>Title 4</h1>
                        <p>Just some content</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div>
                        <h1>Title 5</h1>
                        <p>Just some content</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Anyone any idea how I could fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I havent tested this but it may work wrap the content inside the li element in a div and the put the "just some content" in a p element

```
 <div class="app">
    <div class="list-wrapper">
        <ul>
            <li>
              <div>
                <h1>Title 1</h1>
                <p>jsut some content</p>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div>
                <h1>Title 2</h1>
                <p>jsut some content</p>
              </div>
            </li>
          <li>
              <div>
                <h1>Title 3</h1>
                <p>jsut some content</p>
              </div>
            </li>
          <li>
              <div>
                <h1>Title 4</h1>
                <p>jsut some content</p>
              </div>
            </li>
          <li>
              <div>
                <h1>Title 5</h1>
                <p>jsut some content</p>
              </div>
            </li>
          <li>
              <div>
                <h1>Title 6</h1>
                <p>jsut some content</p>
              </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```